# Extract images and other components in a Word ContentControl?

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-word, vsto, word-2010

c# VSTO

How to insert an image with some caption in a rich text contentcontrol in word 2010.
the property formattedtext doesnt even accept a range object

Comment: Work with the content control's .Range object directly.

Comment: I need to go through the formatted text. Insert/Remove stuff if needed. Save it to SQL and get it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an image to a rich text content control is pretty simple, all you have to do is add it to the `Range.InlineShapes` collection.

To retrieve images from a Word document you can do the following:

1. Loop through all the content controls in the document
2. If content control has an image, copy it to clipboard
3. Retrieve the Image object from clipboard
4. Do any required processing on the image(save to disk,database e.t.c)

Here's an example:

Add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll to be allow use of the [Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class

```
    string imagePath = @"D:\microsoft.jpg";
    string title = "Microsoft";
    Word.ContentControls cc = this.Application.ActiveDocument.ContentControls;

    //Add a rich content control,add an image to the rich content control
    var richContentControl = cc.Add(Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRichText);
    richContentControl.Range.FormattedText.Text = title;

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(imagePath))
    {
        Word.InlineShape image = richContentControl.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagePath);
        image.Height = 70;
        image.Width = 100;

        //Retrieve all images from content controls and save to disk
        foreach (Word.ContentControl c in cc)
        {
            if (c.Range.InlineShapes.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Word.InlineShape shape in c.Range.InlineShapes)
                {
                    shape.Range.Copy();
                    if (System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.ContainsImage())
                    {
                        System.Drawing.Image clipboardImage = Clipboard.GetImage();
                        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"D:\imageName.jpg");
                        clipboardImage.Save(path);
                    }
                    Clipboard.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I lose the positioning of the image.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything? Your original question was "How to insert an image with some caption in a rich text contentcontrol in word 2010?" and I'm showing you how this can be done in the example above